# Take one word out of response string - AJAX/JAVA

Tags: java, ajax, request, substring

I got the following problem:

I get content from another site and as response I get the following:
    - Wednesday, May 21, 2014 at 7:00PM (The month (may here) is the String that varies here)
    - Thursday, June 12, 2014 at 7:00PM (The month (june here))
    - ...

Now I ONLY want to get MAY/JUNE/ ... out of the response String I get

Any idea's how i can do this easily? I thought about .substr()

Comment: try your thoughts out, and see how it goes

Comment: Once you get the String, its origin is not relevant. Search the JS/Java (why do you mix the terms?) solution for that.

Comment: I just want to get each month out of each string i receive (months are variable length)